# Angular2 importing similar modules from a common point

Tags: angular, typescript

I have organized my application in form of ng modules and am also using primeng2 components.
THe primeng2 components requires one to import them in every module that is

I have two modules

```
1. users modules has users component which uses datatable module(primeng2)

2. trucks modules having rtruck component which uses datatable module(from primeng2)
```

My code has alot of repetiton since in every module i have to do

```
imports :[DatatabeModule] //other modules are also here eg 10modules
```

How can i add a central module imports such that

```
in the cental i can import all primeng2 modules and then in my respective modules i can
```

1. users module

   import : [centralmodule]
2. trucks module

   import:[centralModule]

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe you can do what you're trying, and that if a component is in a module you need to to import it into any other module you'd want to use it in.

One item that may be an option is to look at combining all of your common components into one shared module, and then just import that one into all of your modules. There's no global availability in Angular without importing it into all modules.